# How to convert scalastyle-result.xml into readable report

Tags: scala, playframework, coding-style, scalastyle

I am working on setting up various analysis tool for scala project. One of them is checkstyle and I am using 'scalastyle' for that purpose.

This plugin produces not easily readable scalastyle-result.xml as a result of running. Is there a way to convert this XML into some other readable format? 
The idea is to generate the report as part of CI (with is not a problem), and also expose the report to the public (ideally in HTML).

Any other checkstyle tool might work as well if that makes the problem easier to solve.

Thanks,

Comment: XML can be easily converted to any other readable format by XSLT

Comment: Yes, that is true, however I was hoping that there is already existing built tool to do it. I know number of them in pho world, that show all the violations in the code browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scalastyle-result.xml` has exactly the same format as checkstyle result format - this was done deliberately. Anything that works on checkstyle output will work on scalastyle output.

Using the checkstyle plugin for jenkins, specify "Publish Checkstyle analysis results", use the output file, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I am wondering if there is anyway to generate scalastyle reports into maven site plugin reports.